# In a $\triangle ABC$, $\angle B = \frac{π}{3}$ and $\sin A \cdot \sin C = m$. Then we have to find all possible values of $m$.

Tags: trigonometry

In a $\triangle ABC$, $\angle B = \frac{π}{3}$ and $\sin A \cdot \sin C = m$. Then we have to find all possible values of $m$.

What I did was wrote $C=\frac{2π}{3}-A$. Hence

$$\sin A \cdot \sin(\frac{2π}{3}-A)=m$$.

Further I wrote $\sin(\frac{2π}{3}-A)$ as

$$\sin C \cdot \cos D - \sin D \cdot \cos C$$

Later I assumed $\sin A=t$ but I got a polynomial of degree 4. Which I was unable to solve.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

> In a $\triangle ABC$, $\angle B=\tfrac\pi3$ and $\sin A\sin C=m$. Find
>   all possible values of $m$.

Let $S$ and $R$ denote the 
area and the radius of the circumscribed circle, respectively.

WLOG let $R=1$ for convenience. Then

\begin{align}
\sin A\sin B\sin C&=\frac{S}{2\,R^2}
,\\
\tfrac{\sqrt3}2\,m&=\tfrac12\,S
,\\
m&=\tfrac{\sqrt3}3\,S
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

So the range of $m$ is

\begin{align}
m&=(\tfrac{\sqrt3}3\,S_{\min},\,\tfrac{\sqrt3}3\,S_{\max})
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Recall that $\triangle ABC$ is inscribed in the unit circle,
so $S_{\min}=0$ corresponds to the degenerate triangles
with either $A=0$ or $C=0$.
And since
the fixed angle $B=\tfrac\pi3$ 
fixes also the base $|AC|=\sqrt3$,
the maximum of the area
is reached in the equilateral triangle,
$S_{\max}=\tfrac{3\,\sqrt3}4$ and the answer is

\begin{align}
0<m&\le\tfrac34
.
\end{align}

Comment: [+1] Sound geometric solution.

Comment: Very nice solution:)

Answer (score 1):

First, $0 \leq A,C \leq 180^{\circ}$. Therefore $\sin A, \sin C \geq 0$, so $m \geq 0$

$$\sin A \cdot \sin C = m$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \sin A \cdot \sin (\frac{2\pi}{3}-A) = m$$

Using the trig identity $\sin A \cdot \sin B = \frac{1}{2} (\cos (A-B) - \cos (A+B))$, we get:

$$\frac{1}{2} (\cos (2A - \frac{2\pi}{3}) - \cos \frac{2\pi}{3}) = m$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \cos (2A - \frac{2\pi}{3}) + \frac{1}{2} = 2m$$

From here we can know the range of m. Since $-1 \le \cos (2A - \frac{2\pi}{3}) \le 1$ and $m \geq 0$, the final answer will be:

$$m \in [0,  \frac{3}{4}]$$

Comment: When you reach $\Leftrightarrow \cos (2A - \frac{2\pi}{3}) + \frac{1}{2} = 2m$ it is not necessary to go further ! The range of values for $m$ is immediate... knowing that $A \in (0,2 \pi/3)$.

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't notice that

Comment: Shouldn't $m$ be positive, considering that none of the angles is $\ge 180°$?

Comment: Your result gives the range $m \in [0,3/4]$ which is the result awaited by the OP.

Comment: @JeanMarie, Allawonder Oh sorry, my mistake, my bad. I was quite carelessly when answering. I fixed my post. Thank you guy a lot:D